# Type for style attribute passed to function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Please consider this typescript function

```
 function button(style: any, func: ()=>void, img: string) {
    return (
      <button
        className="Reader_Button"
        style={style}
        onClick={func}
      >
        <img src={img} alt="" />
        Back
      </button>
    );
  }
```

What is the correct type for the first argument `style`? I feel like it should be something like HTMLElementStyle but I can't find the right incantation.

**Sorry, I wasn't sufficiently clear. I want to know what type to use to replace the "any" in `style: any`. The typescript definitions handle checking the types of the supplied members of the object.**

I'm talking about definition of the function, not application.

Comment: did you tried "width=100px, font-size: 12px;"? or is it possible to have these arguments put outside.

Comment: ReactJS style properties are just maps, aren't they?

Comment: `style` needs an key-value object. Something like: `{color: "red"}`. So in full it becomes `style={{color: "red"}}`. Just note that css properties with a dash, are camel-cased in React. So `font-size` would instead be written as `fontSize`.

Comment: See my edit above. I know how to use the function. I want to know how to properly declare it so that it checks the types of its arguments the way typescript does for the style attribute.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

The type is `React.CSSProperties`. You can find this in VSCode by writing `<div 
style={{}}>` and pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> when having your cursor in the `style` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. There must be more to it than that though. If I declare that argument to have type React.CSSProperties then I get complaints about trying to assign objects like `{width: em(4), height: em(4),fontSize: em(0.75),alignSelf: 'flex-end'}` to it. But I don't get that error supplying the same object directly to a style={} attribute on node. They've somehow made the style attribute more accepting.

Comment: @GaryBishop and what complaints exactly are you getting?

Comment: Consider this [larger segment of the code](https://github.com/gbishop/tar-heel-reader-17/blob/master/src/NavFrame.tsx#L36-L58). If I change the declaration of bstyle on line 36 to bstyle: React.CSSProperties I get errors like shown [here](https://gist.github.com/gbishop/6aa2c898d1b63e0cc17a6dbab7e0500c). I don't understand why the div style attribute can accept that object but my CSSProperties argument can't. BTW, I know about the strange 'center' as 'center' fix but why isn't it always required?

Comment: @GaryBishop it seems you have an old version of `@types/react` package. Please try upgrading it. Also, there is a note in the source stating the interface is not complete: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L712

Comment: Upgrading doesn't help. The key surprise for me is that it doesn't complain on the assignment to style on the div but does on the function with the same apparent declaration. I've had the same issue with variables. I'm missing something.

Comment: @GaryBishop This is really strange. I suggest opening an issue on the DefinitelyTyped project.

Answer (score 5):

The style prop on regular DOM elements should be in the form of an object where the keys are the css attributes.

Example: 
`<div style={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "black" }} />`

Notice that in the case of attributes containing dashes, they become camel cased. For instance `background-color` becomes `backgroundColor`.

[React style documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

Comment: See my clarification above. I know how to call it. I'm looking for info on how to declare it so that it checks types like the style attribute does.

Comment: Wow, my issue was using 'text-align'! Once I updated it to 'textAlign' it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for me work "import CSS from csstype" && wrap to quotes 'maxHeight': '120px'

```
import React from 'react';
import CSS from 'csstype';
    
const shortList = () => {
    const listStylus: CSS.Properties = {
        'maxHeight': '120px',
        'overflow': 'hidden',
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <ul style={listStylus} >
            <li>Item element 1</li>
            <li>Item element 2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
}

export default shortList
```

Comment: You should clarify that the csstype package needs to be installed too https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype

Answer (score -1):

CSSStyleDeclaration
It becomes available as soon as you have typescript in your project.
There are some more but I think this is the one.

Comment: `const cssProp = keyof CSSStyleDeclaration = 'fontSize'`