# Pass style as props in react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-component

I created a event-box component in react. What I want is whenever is it called, I passed color values as props which later get used to set its border. Currently, I set two hardcoded class names and passed them as props with the component. Is there any other way to do so as I won't able to add all the color class names in my stylesheet.

Component code

```
import React from 'react';

class EventBox extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state={

        }
    }
    render()
    {
        const style={
            marginBottom:'0px'
        }
        const list={
            display:'inline-flex',
            width:'100%',
            marginBottom:'10px'
        }
        const listItem={
            flex:'1',
            display:'flex'
        }
        return(
            <div className={this.props.class}>
                <ul className="list list-inline" style={list}>
                    <li className="list-inline-item color-golden" style={listItem}>1 March 2020</li>
                    <li className="list-inline-item color-red flex flex-end" style={listItem}>200 People Interested</li>
                </ul>
                <h3 className="sub-heading roboto">Title</h3>
                <p className="paragraph roboto" style={style}>Saket, New Delhi</p>
                <p className="paragraph roboto" style={style}>Time: 05:00 P.M - 06:30 P.M</p>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default EventBox;
```

```
 <EventBox class="col-md-12 event-box-container red-border" />
 <EventBox class="col-md-12 event-box-container green-border" />
```

CSS

```
.event-box-container.red-border{
    border-top: 8px solid red;
}
.event-box-container.green-border{
    border-top: 8px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can just pass the dynamic styles to the component as an object.

**For Class-Based Components:**

```js
import React from 'react';

class EventBox extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="col-md-12 event-box-container" style={this.props.style}>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default EventBox;
```

**For Functional Components:**

```js
import React from 'react';

const EventBox = ({ style }) => {
    return(
        <div className="col-md-12 event-box-container" style={style}>
        </div>
    )
}
export default EventBox;
```

**Usage**

```js
<EventBox style={{ borderTop: '8px solid red' }} />
<EventBox style={{ borderTop: '8px solid green' }}  />
```

If you are using TypeScript, you can add auto completion in your IDE when passing the `style` prop to the `EventBox` component.

```
import React from 'react';

const EventBox = ({ style }: { style?: React.CSSProperties }) => {
    return(
        <div className="col-md-12 event-box-container" style={style}>
        </div>
    )
}
export default EventBox;
```

Comment: What is the official name for this pattern of using as JS object with `style=`? Is this _CSS in JS_?

Comment: @CodeFinity it is simply passing inline styles as a JS object

Comment: @Anatol how to add autocomplete in vscode as well?

Comment: @Aviral you would have to use something like TypeScript. Here is how you would do it with TS https://stackoverflow.com/a/45116780/11804213

Comment: This works with inline style , but how to pass when style is defined scss file?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#react-native). For example:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

const Component = ({style}) => {

  return (
    <View style={style}>
    {/* More components here */}
    <View>
  )
}

const Styled = styled(Component)`
  padding-top: 10px;
`
```