# How to type this object with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the following example, I'm not sure what the type should be for the `style` variable:

```js
export const getPaddingOrMarginStyle = (arrValue: number[], key: string) => {
// The key can only contain "margin" and "padding"

  const style = {}; // <--------------- what is type??

  if (arrValue.length === 4) {
    style.key = `${arrValue[0]}px ${arrValue[1]}px ${arrValue[2]}px ${arrValue[3]}px`;
  }
  if (arrValue.length === 2) {
    style[key] = `${arrValue[0]}px ${arrValue[1]}px`;
  }

  if (arrValue.length === 1) {
    style[key] = `${arrValue}px`;
  }

  if (arrValue.length === 1 && key === 'margin') {
    if (arrValue[0] === 0) {
      style.margin = `${arrValue}px auto`;
    } else {
      style.margin = `${arrValue}px`;
    }
  }

  return style;  // i want result style { margin: '10px 10px 10px 10px'} or { padding: '10px 10px 10px 10px'}
};
```

Comment: **Explain the technical problem** please. Don't just spam in more text.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```js
type MyStyle = {
  margin?: string;
  padding?: string;
}
```

And then use it as such:

```js
const style: MyStyle = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get by without writing a function to add style such as padding and margin.

While I don't know your technical problem, I would say start small, with simple css classes and use those classnames in your TypeScript components.

Once you get the hang of it, you can make the code more complex and push for functions to do more complex styles that are based on conditions.

Good luck on your TypeScript learning journey.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick search lead me to this stack overflow: [Type for style attribute passed to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019775/type-for-style-attribute-passed-to-function).

Looks like the type is `React.CSSProperties`.